# Why is this the matrix of the linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

We have a vector space of cubic polynomials and a linear transformation $T(a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3) = (a_0 + a_1) + (a_1 + a_2)x + (a_2 + a_3)x^2 + (a_3 + a_4)x^3$. what is the matrix of this transformation with respect to the basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ and why?

Comment: What are $T(1), T(x), T(x^2)$ and $T(x^3)$? What are the corresponding coordinate vectors with respect to the standard basis? It's also probably a good idea to mention which vector space you're referencing, I'm guessing it's the set of polynomials with degree at most 3, but over what field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field, and let $V$ be the vector space (over $k$) of all polynomials of degree at most $3$ with coefficients in $k$. Consider the linear transformation $T: V \to V$ given in the question, and the basis $\mathcal{B} := \{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$ of $V$. We call this the standard basis of $V$.

For each $p \in V$, the coordinate vector of $p$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$, $[p]_\mathcal{B}$, is the element of $k^4$ given by the coefficients in the expansion of $p$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$. I.e., $ [p]_\mathcal{B} = (a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3)$ from the expansion $p = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$.

We want to find a matrix $A$ such that for each $p \in V$, 
\begin{align}A [p]_\mathcal{B} = [T(p)]_\mathcal{B}. \label{eq1} \tag{1}\end{align} I.e., we want a coordinate representation of $T$ with respect to the standard basis. The way to do this is to find $[T(x^i)]_\mathcal{B}$ for each $0 \leq i \leq 3$, and stick these into the columns of $A$.

So let $A$ be the matrix $\left( [T(1)]_\mathcal{B} \big| [T(x)]_\mathcal{B} \big| [T(x^2)]_\mathcal{B} \big| [T(x^3)]_\mathcal{B}\right)$. Suppose $p = a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$ is an element of $V$. Then 
\begin{align} 
A [p]_\mathcal{B} &= \left( [T(1)]_\mathcal{B} \big| [T(x)]_\mathcal{B} \big| [T(x^2)]_\mathcal{B} \big| [T(x^3)]_\mathcal{B}\right) \begin{pmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{pmatrix}\\
                  &= a_0 [T(1)]_\mathcal{B} + a_1 [T(x)]_\mathcal{B} + a_2 [T(x^2)]_\mathcal{B} + a_3 [T(x^3)]_\mathcal{B} \\ 
                  &= [T(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3)]_\mathcal{B},
\end{align} since taking coordinates is linear. Therefore, $A [p]_\mathcal{B} = [T(p)]_\mathcal{B}.$ The matrix $A$ satisfies property \eqref{eq1}. In fact, $A$ is the only matrix satisfying property \eqref{eq1} (why?).

$A$ is called the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$. Notice that so far I haven't made any reference to the formula that defines $T$. This works for any linear transformation $T: V \to V$.

---

This problem is a particular case of the following more general problem: given a linear transformation $T: V \to W$ between finite dimensional vector spaces, and bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ of $V$ and $W$ respectively, can we find a matrix $A$ such that for each $v \in V$, $A[v]_\mathcal{B} = [T(v)]_\mathcal{C}$?

The answer is yes, and the matrix $A$ is unique. It's called the matrix of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ in the domain and $\mathcal{C}$ in the codomain.

If we let $n := \text{dim}(V)$ and $m := \text{dim}(W)$, then $A$ is the $m \times n$ matrix given by \begin{align}A = ([T(b_1)]_\mathcal{C} \big| \dots \big| [T(b_n)]_\mathcal{C}).\end{align}